# Ruby on Rails with Postgres Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm currently having an issue with Ruby on Rails (4.2.5) and Postgres (9.4.5) Arrays.  The model attribute believes it is a type String which isn't working when trying to assign an Array.  My migration has:

```
# create a urls array
t.text :urls, array: true, default: []
```

Then in my controller I have:

```
def create
  @lead = Lead.new(lead_params)
  ...
end

def lead_params
  params.require(:lead).permit(:name, :base_url, urls: [])
end
```

Unfortunately, when debugging with `byebug` I see:

```
(byebug)  lead_params['urls'].class
Array
(byebug) @lead.urls.class
String
(byebug) @lead.urls      
"[\"asd\", \"\", \"\", \"\", \"\"]"
```

The `:urls` attribute of my Lead class isn't thinking it is an Array.  I have no code in my model (which might be the problem?).

Any thoughts much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to change type from `text` to `string`

```
t.string :urls, array: true, default: []
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion @wizard-of-ogz ... unfortunately no dice. I tried with string and it is having the same issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the comment from @muistooshort I found the database schema was indeed wrong.  Somehow in all of my Docker wisdom I had managed to get `schema.rb` out of sync with the actual migrations.

Now the `schema.rb` correctly shows:

```
t.text     "urls",            default: [],              array: true
```

And everything works as expected :-)

The trick was the run the following:

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

I think I had previously run some `rake db:rest` commands which seem to have led to the issue.

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this. Have you looked at the table's schema inside PostgreSQL? Connect to your database with `psql` from the command line and `\d leads` to see what the table really looks like.

Comment: Good call @muistooshort ... database is wrong.  `urls` is of type `text` when I think it should be `array`.   Now to figure out what is up with the migration.

Comment: You can also use `rake db:migrate VERSION=<older migration number>` to reverse recent migrations and then `rake db:migrate` to rerun them.

Comment: Thanks @PJSCopeland, will make use of this next time.  I had been modifying the initial migration manually which probably got me into the mess in the first place.